# SQLiteOpenHelper suddenly becomes null

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am new to Android and am making my first app. I made a SQLite table using a contract and helper class. That works fine. I then wrap the database in a ContentProvider, which also seems to work just fine. Here's how I instantiate the SQLiteOpenHelper in my Content Provider class:

```
public boolean onCreate() {
    mTestDb = new TestDbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}
```

I then have two helper methods in the onCreate() method of the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    provider = new TestProvider();
    providerInsert();
    providerShow();
}
```

`provider` was declared as a class variable previously. Here are the helper methods:

```
public void providerInsert() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TestContract.FIRST_COLUMN, 3);
    values.put(TestContract.SECOND_COLUMN, "hello.");
    final Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(TestContract.CONTENT_URI, values);
}

public void providerShow() {
    Cursor cursor = provider.query(
            TestContract.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {TestContract._ID, TestContract.FIRST_COLUMN, TestContract.SECOND_COLUMN},
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    int id = cursor.getInt(0);
    int first = cursor.getInt(1);
    String second = cursor.getString(2);

    String print = "At column" + id + ": " + first + ", " + second;

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), print, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
```

Heres the kicker: `providerInsert()` works just fine! I'm getting a values for `url` and everything looks great. Then, it goes to `providerShow()` and `mTestDb` is now suddenly null! Here are the insert() and query() methods for my Content Provider:

```
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mTestDb.getWritableDatabase();

    switch(matcher.match(uri)) {

        case FIRST_CASE: {
            long id = db.insert(
                    TestContract.TABLE_NAME,
                    null,
                    values
            );

            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(TestContract.CONTENT_URI, id);

        }

        default: {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mTestDb.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rCursor;

    switch(matcher.match(uri)) {

        case FIRST_CASE: {
            rCursor = db.query(
                TestContract.TABLE_NAME,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder
            );
            break;
        }

        default: {
            rCursor = null;
        }
    }

    return rCursor;
}
```

As I previously said, `mTestDb` becomes null by the time the code gets to `query()`. I feel like this is just a silly error and it has a simple fix, but I've been pouring over the code for hours to no avail. Could someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit 1 - Here's the `TestProvider` class:

```
package com.example.android.testapp.data;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.Uri;

import java.net.URI;

/**
 * Created by Shubhang on 2/5/2015.
 */
public class TestProvider extends ContentProvider {
    SQLiteOpenHelper mTestDb = null;
    private static final int FIRST_CASE = 1;

private static UriMatcher matcher;
static {
    matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    matcher.addURI(TestContract.AUTHORITY, null, FIRST_CASE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mTestDb = new TestDbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mTestDb.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rCursor;

    switch(matcher.match(uri)) {

        case FIRST_CASE: {
            rCursor = db.query(
                TestContract.TABLE_NAME,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder
            );
            break;
        }

        default: {
            rCursor = null;
        }
    }

    return rCursor;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    String rUri;

    switch (matcher.match(uri)) {
        case FIRST_CASE: {
            rUri = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/" + TestContract.AUTHORITY;
        }

        default : {
            rUri = null;
        }
    }

    return rUri;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mTestDb.getWritableDatabase();

    switch(matcher.match(uri)) {

        case FIRST_CASE: {
            long id = db.insert(
                    TestContract.TABLE_NAME,
                    null,
                    values
            );

            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(TestContract.CONTENT_URI, id);

        }

        default: {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

Edit 2 - Here's some logging I added to the `onCreate()`, `query()`, and `insert()` methods, respectively:

```
Log.e(TAG, "onCreate(): " + this.toString());

Log.e(TAG, "query(): " + this.toString());

Log.e(TAG, "insert(): " + this.toString());
```

Here's the error statements in logcat:

```
02-07 14:37:17.367    9488-9488/com.example.android.testapp E/TestProvider: onCreate(): com.example.android.testapp.data.TestProvider@415f4ad8
02-07 14:37:17.453    9488-9488/com.example.android.testapp E/TestProvider﹕ insert(): com.example.android.testapp.data.TestProvider@415f4ad8
02-07 14:37:17.524    9488-9488/com.example.android.testapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.testapp/com.example.android.testapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.android.testapp.data.TestProvider.query(TestProvider.java:38)
            at com.example.android.testapp.MainActivity.providerShow(MainActivity.java:74)
            at com.example.android.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As you can see, my application doesn't even reach the `query()` method before breaking.

Comment: What is `provider` in `providerShow()`? Where is it declared?

Comment: It is a class level `TestProvider` (which is my Content Provider class): `TestProvider provider;`. It's the same `provider` that's instantiated in `onCreate()` in MainActivity.

Comment: It's declared right under the MainActivity class header: `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TestProvider provider; //...}`

Comment: Are the `insert` and `query` methods in your `MainActivity` as well?

Comment: Yes, but the only times `insert` and `query` are used is in `providerInsert()` and `providerShow()`. Does that answer your question? Or did I totally miss what you were asking?

Comment: Yes it does. Please post your `TestProvider` class.

Comment: I added an edit to the original post.

Comment: indeed it doesn't make sense. onCreate is called only once when your app is loaded, so the instance can't be null, the only way this could happen is if you ContentProvider for some reason is deleted and recreated and when query is called your onCreate was not called yet, which should not happen on android system.
did you try creating a C'tor and putting some logs to see what happens ? also you can try and print the ContentProvider instance (this,toString()) and see if it's teh same refference in query and insert.

Comment: I added another edit with some logs. Sorry, I don't know what C'tor is, but I did try printing `this.toString()` as you suggested.

Comment: I noticed that in `providerInsert`, you have `getContentResolver().insert` but in `providerShow` you have `provider.query`. Is there some reason you are using `getContentResolver` in `providerInsert` and `provider` in `providerShow`?

Comment: That was it! I needed to have `getContentResolver().query` for it to work! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! In order to query the `TestProvider`, I needed to use a Content Resolver in my `providerShow()` method.